# InitialLOBFetchSize of -1 causes IsDBNull of an empty CLOB to return true

Tags: .net, oracle, ado.net, oracle11g, odp.net

Today I found the `OracleCommand.InitialLOBFetchSize` property ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleCommandClass.htm#BABEGDHA)). Because I'm using NHibernate (which always accesses all values returned from a `DataReader`) I've set it to -1 for all new `OracleCommands` in my application (which brought a huge performance gain when selecting many CLOBs).

But then I noticed several new bugs in my application. All of them have the same source: Suddenly `OracleDataReader.IsDBNull()` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/OracleDataReaderClass.htm#i1006661)) returns true for empty CLOBs! This is 100% reproducible, setting it back to 0 or a positive value brings `IsDBNull()` back to its correct behaviour.

Has anyone an idea how this bug can be prevented while still getting complete LOBs without additional round-trips?

I've noticed that setting `InitialLOBFetchSize` to a positive value affects the `OracleDataReader.RowSize` value, whereas 0 and -1 result in the same `RowSize` value. Is there any disadvantage in setting `InitialLOBFetchSize` to a big value (some MB)?

I'm using ODP.NET 11.2.0.3.0 (also tried 11.2.0.2.0) with .NET 4.0 and an Oracle 11g Release 2 server.

Comment: FYI: There is an official Oracle bug entry for this problem. The bug ID is 14279177.

Comment: I just ran into this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some testing showed that using big values (>= 1 MB) for `InitialLOBFetchSize` brings the performance back down (as bad as 0).

I'll use a value that covers most of my CLOBs (5-10 KB) until someone has a real solution.